# Why does this bool expression with 'or' return True?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am still working with bool logic.

I have this snippet and I don't understand why the result comes out True.

```
flag = False
print(flag)
flag = flag or True
print(flag)
```

you get:

```
>>False
>>True
```

Why is this happening? I am not sure how this works.

Is or supposed to give you any instance where the expression is True?

I get why this happens:

```
check = (7 > 60) or (7 < 10)
print(check)
```

7 is less than 10, so the check expression is True

Thanks for the explanation. Just trying to work out bools in my head.

Comment: If either flag or True is true, the expression evaluates to True. If that were an "and", it would be False.

Comment: `x or y` is true if `x` is true or `y` is true. So `anything or True` is always `True`.

Comment: you may want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be fixed by reading literally any document that describes boolean logic.

Comment: `False or True` gives `True`, and `True of False` gives `True`, and `True or True`  gives `True`. Only `False or False` gives `False`

Comment: @Barmar `anything or True` is not necessarily always `True`. For example `1 or True` evaluates to `1` -- Perhaps what you mean is that it will always pass a truthy test, IE an if clause such as `if anything or True` will always catch.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I get what you're saying, but sytech makes a good point here. pirate = False, pirate = False or True, then pirate = True. On the other side, pirate = 'arr' or True will result in pirate = 'arr' ... and pirate = True or 'arr' will be pirate = True. This case also deals with assignment and datatypes, clearly datatype plays a role here. Which is a programming topic and not only logic. I don't think it's off topic.

Comment: @paintedcupcakes. Everything you are describing is clearly explained in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in logic,

```
(False or True) == True
```

The `or` expression is true, if any of the two arguments is true. That is the case here.

Comment: Your current python expression is evaluated as `False or (True == True)` which does not convey the original message. You should use a parenthesis as in: `(False or True) == True`

Comment: Thanks, changed that.